# Mkvirtualenv - cannot install -r requirements.txt

Tags: django, terminal, virtualenv

I am a brand new Noob and have no idea how to make this Mkvirtualenv install the proper requirements for a tutorial I forked [here](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial/).

I made the Mkvirtualenv(django-angular-tutorial) but when I try to install the requirements (which is in the forked folder on my desktop) it gives me this error saying that the directory is not found.

[image]

Do I have to manually put this forked folder into the Mkvirtualenv folder for it to find it? Or how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

"No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'". So, there is no requirements file.

From the  `~` in your prompt, it appears you're still in your home directory, and never cd-ed into the cloned/forked folder. Your requirements file is probably there.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how I would then get out of the home directory and into the coned/forked folder?

Comment: Ehm, sorry, but if you don't know how to change to directory on your system, you really shouldn't be cloning repositories and using mkvirtualenv. Because you'll be running into lots of problems later on. First learn how to get around on a command line in a terminal.

Comment: Thats not very encouraging...lol I fixed it. Sorry for a lame question, but I am sure someone who is just trying out would like to learn. These kind of tips will answer his/her question and therefore save him a lot of time and help learn it along the way...So I disagree with that statement.

Answer (score -1):

**To answer my own question:**

I was not in the proper directory. So terminal came back with an error saying that it could not find "requirements.txt"

What I had to do was first navigate to to the folder that the "requirements.txt" was located in.(The folder was located on my desktop)

**In terminal I did this:**

1) Navigated to my Forked Folder

*Perez-Austin:~ perau$ cd /Users/perau/Desktop/folderThatHasRequirements*

2) Now you are pointed to the right directory and should show up like this:

*Perez-Austin:folderThatHasRequirements perau$*

3) "Create" or "Workon" your MkVirtualEnv (mine is called django-angular-tutorial)

*Perez-Austin:folderThatHasRequirements perau$ workon django-angular-tutorial*

4) Then Install your -r requirements.txt to your MkVirtualEnv

*(django-angular-tutorial)Perez-Austin:folderThatHasRequirements perau$ pip install -r requirements.txt*

5) It should install